# como enviar el valor de varias variables onchange varios selects por ajax a un archivo php para hacer un consulta y mostrar los datos en un select

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

es decir que varie y que cambie dependiendo de la seleccion de los selects si cambia uno que filtre la condicion que si cambia a otro que lo filtre y asi etc.. he intentado enviando las variables del valor onchange de los selects por ajax a un archivo php hacer la consulta y mostrar pero solo se cumple con una variable
este el codigo de la conexion

```
<?php


class Constantes {
    const HOST = "localhost";
    const USER = "root";
    const PASSWORD = "";
    const DB = "teayudoeps";
}

class Configuracion extends Constantes{

    public $mysql = NULL;   

    public function conectarBD($bd = Constantes::DB)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
        $this->mysql = new mysqli(Constantes::HOST, Constantes::USER, Constantes::PASSWORD, $bd);   
        mysqli_set_charset($this->mysql, "utf8");   
        return $this->mysql;

    }

    
    public function consulta($query)
    {           
        $i = 0;
        $contenedor = array();  
        $result = mysqli_query($this->mysql, $query) or die("Error en la consulta: $query ".mysqli_error());
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $contenedor[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
        }
        
        return $contenedor;
    }

    public function actualizacion($query)
    {
        mysqli_query($this->mysql, $query) or die("Error en la consulta: $query ".mysqli_error());
    }

    public function desconectarDB()
    {
            mysqli_close($this->mysql);
    }

}
```

asi muestro los selects principales

Departamento

```
                <select id="id_departamento" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                    <option value=" 0">Seleccione</option>
                    <?php  
         
                         $conf = new Configuracion();
                             $conf->conectarBD();                                                                             
                             $consulta = "SELECT id_departamento,departamento FROM departamentos";
                             $rst1 = $conf->consulta($consulta);
                              for($i = 0; $i < count($rst1); $i++)
                         {                                                   
                            echo '<option value="'.$rst1[$i]["id_departamento"].'">'.$rst1[$i]["departamento"].'</option>';                                                    
                             }
                            $conf->desconectarDB();
                             ?>
                </select>
                <br>
```

asi hago el siguiente select junto la funcion ajax para que carguen los municipios acorde al departamento
Municipio

```
                <select id="id_municipio" name="municipio" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                </select>
                <!--funcion ajax para traer el municipio acorde al departamento-->
                <script>
                     $(document).ready(function() {
                    var municipio = $('#id_municipio');
                         $('#id_departamento').change(function() {
                             var id_departamento = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                   data: {
                                      id_departamento: id_departamento
                                },
                                    dataType: 'html',
                                   type: 'POST',
                                   url: '../../getmunicipio.php',
                               }).done(function(data) {
                                   municipio.html(data);
                               });
                          });
                       });
                </script>
```

Comment: Por favor, dale un título descriptivo a tu pregunta y luego explica el problema en el cuerpo de la misma, tratando de usar correctamente la ortografía (mayúsculas, signos de puntuación, etc). Parecería que empiezas a exponer el problema en el título y como se agotó el espacio seguiste en el cuerpo ... Además, no logra entenderse concretamente cuál es el problema, ni dónde es el problema. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Me parce que en el select id="id_departamento" te falta hacer un llamado a una funcion con el evento onchange=funcion(); , y ahí hacer el llamado para cargar el contenido del siguiente select mediante ajax.

Answer (score 0):

principalmente este código deberías de ser algo como esto:

```
var municipio = $('#id_municipio');
                         $('#id_departamento').change(function() {
                             var id_departamento = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                   data: {
                                      id_departamento: id_departamento
                                },
                                    dataType: 'html',
                                   type: 'POST',
                                   url: '../../getmunicipio.php',
                               }).done(function(data) {
                                   municipio.html(data);
                               });
                          });
                       });
```

*Actualización de como debería de ser*

```
var municipio = $('#id_municipio');
                         $('#id_departamento').change(function() {
                             var id_departamento = $(this).val();
                             getMunicipio(id_departamento);
                            
                       });

function getMunicipio(id_departamento){

$.ajax({
        data: {id_departamento: id_departamento},
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../../getmunicipio.php',
   }).done(function(data) {
            municipio.html(data);
   });
 });
}
```

Partiendo tu código en dos funciones, para hacer las cosas más estructuradas.

Por otro lado, acostumbrate a usar `.on` es decir:

```
$('#id_departamento').on("change", function() {
                                 var id_departamento = $(this).val();
                                
                           });
```

Es más eficiente, más actual, infórmate un poco sobre esto. Por otro lado el `datatype` no es necesario. ya que le vas a mandar un parámetro a tu php con el data, y con el datatype le estás pasando html cosa no correcta. Se le pasa un ID integer y haces la query.

Con todo esto dejamos el código mas estructurado y más legible. Ahora está el problema de que solo te recoge una variable. Solo le estás pasando un valor en el data del ajax. Ahí tendrías que pasarle los valores de tus selects seleccionados:

```
data: {
     id_departamento: id_departamento,
     id_ciudad: valorDeTuOtroSelect
},
```

Espero haberte guiado un poco con tu proyecto. Un saludo y suerte

Comment: si mira es que hay un select final y ese select final depende de la seleccion del municipio de otro select que se llama eps y otro select que se llama regimen es decir por ejemplo si selecciona en el municipio x municipio que aparezcan tales hospitales por ejemplo los hospitales que sean de esa localidad o municipio bien luego cuando seleccione la eps que aparezcan solo los que tenga convenio con esa eps y que sean del pueblo luego que cuando seleccione el regimen que me muestre solo los que tenga convenio con ese regimen esa eps y que sean de ese pueblo es decir depende de 3 sabes como hacer?